# SSH remote forwarding results in 404 Not Found

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

On a remote server, `remote1.myorg.io`, I am unable to access a web resource, say, `http://spaa.acm.org/2020/SPAA2020TutorialProgram.pdf`. So, on the remote server, I'm using ssh to create a server on 127.0.0.0 and access the resource thru there, by forwarding the request back to my local machine (and have my local machine fetch the resource). This is what I'm doing on my local machine:

```
ssh -R 6050:spaa.acm.org:80 remote1.myorg.io
```

Then, on  `remote1.myorg.io`, I do

```
curl -v http://localhost:6050/2020/SPAA2020TutorialProgram.pdf
```

However, I get

```
* About to connect() to localhost port 6050 (#0)
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 6050 (#0)
> GET /2020/SPAA2020TutorialProgram.pdf HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: localhost:6050
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Connection: Keep-Alive
< Content-Type: text/html
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Sun, 15 Nov 2020 00:41:45 GMT
< Server: LiteSpeed
<
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem: The spaa.acm.org server, like many web servers, does something like name-based virtual hosting. That is, it inspects the `Host` header of incoming requests, and can serve different content depending on what hostname the client says it's trying to reach. If you look at the verbose output from `curl`, it includes this header:

```
> Host: localhost:6050
```

...but I'm pretty sure that server doesn't recognize "localhost" as a domain name it should be serving, so you get problems.

Solution 1: You can tell `curl` to fetch the normal URL (including the "spaa.acm.org" domain), but to proxy the connection via localhost:6050:

```
curl -v -x localhost:6050 http://spaa.acm.org/2020/SPAA2020TutorialProgram.pdf -O
* Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 6050 (#0)
> GET http://spaa.acm.org/2020/SPAA2020TutorialProgram.pdf HTTP/1.1
> Host: spaa.acm.org
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Connection: Keep-Alive
< Content-Type: application/pdf
< Last-Modified: Sat, 11 Jul 2020 07:33:05 GMT
< Etag: "168eb-5f096b31-3718a48ea4a1f404;;;"
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Length: 92395
< Date: Sun, 15 Nov 2020 01:24:27 GMT
< Server: LiteSpeed
<
```

(Note the `Host: spaa.acm.org` header.)

Solution 2: Explicitly override the `Host` header:

```
curl -v -H "Host: spaa.acm.org" http://localhost:6050/2020/SPAA2020TutorialProgram.pdf -O
```

I won't include the debug output on this one, suffice to say that it also works.

Comment: Excellent - this works like a charm, thank you.

Comment: Extending this question a bit: what we have discussed so far works for the domain `spaa.acm.org`. Now, I am wondering: what if I'd like to use my local machine as a proxy for *all* domains. Can `ssh` help achieve that?

Comment: I haven't experimented with it, but I think you could use e.g. `ssh -R localhost:6050 ...`to set up a SOCKS proxy rather than a plain TCP tunnel, then use `curl -x socks5://localhost:6050 ...` (or set an env variable: `export ALL_PROXY=socks5://localhost:6050`).